# What's the opposite of hypochondriacal?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

A hypochondriacal person is someone  who is excessively  preoccupied with and worried about his or her health.

Is there a term for the other end of the spectrum -- somebody extremely carefree, especially with regard to his or her health?

Comment: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hyperchondriac

Comment: Looks like the right word. But is it a real word that can be used and understood by most English speaking people?

Comment: _Hyperchondriachal_. Greek _hypo_ and _hyper_ are opposites, precisely parallel to Latin _sub_ and _super_, respectively (PIE initial *s changed to /h/ in Greek). What it means is up to you.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm familiar with words like hyper/hypoglycemia or hyper/hypotension and I can use them with confidence. Can I do the same with hyperchondriasis or Hyperchondriachal? That's what I want to know.

Comment: Like I say, the meaning is up to you. When it's not a common term, an addressee should expect a clear definition on request.

Comment: It's probably not the 'real' word for it, in terms of etymology, since hypochondria literally means beneath the ribs. But because of the common way hypo- and hyper- are usually used, people are likely to understand it and it can become a real word. That said, the more commonly used word is probably 'irresponsible'.

Comment: It's tempting to call the opposite of hypochondria "Black Knightism," after the Black Knight in _Monty Python and the Holy Grail_. King Arthur: Now stand back, worthy adversary. Black Knight: 'Tis but a scratch. King Arthur: A scratch? Your arm's off. Black Knight: No it isn't. King Arthur: What's that then? Black Knight [after a pause]: I've had worse.

Comment: @user55318 "It's probably not the 'real' word for it, in terms of etymology ..." Pedigreed etymology is not a requisite for wordness. Words like gadget, blimp, raunchy, scam, nifty, zit, clobber, gimmick, jazz and googol have all appeared in the last century or two with **no** apparent etymology [tywkiwdbi.blogspot.com]. If 'hyperchondriac' etc become used widely enough, they will be 'real words' in spite of dubious parentage. But don't ask me to tell you if or when that time will come.

Comment: I think it's extremely unlikely that "hyperchondriac" will be widely adopted since it sounds almost identical to its antonym and thus would just cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

**"stoical"** seems to fit.

> stoical (adj) "enduring pain and hardship without showing one’s feelings or complaining" [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stoical)

A stoical or phlegmatic kind of person often underestimates symptoms of diseases.

Comment: I thought "stoic" was the adjective form. (Have you actually heard anyone use "stoical?)

Comment: @Oldbag  Yes, I've read and heard it used in this context. I may be mistaken but I think "stoic" (adj) refers to the Stoics of ancient Greece.

Comment: I've heard "stoic" and "stoical" used interchangeably, ie as adjectives, in the context you describe.  Actually there might be a bias towards "stoic" when it's followed by the noun, and "stoical" as a "standalone" adjective, eg "He's a stoic individual" or "He's very stoical".  Stoic is more common, anyway.

Answer (score -2):

There is the old expression, "hale and hearty" - you could use *hale*, by itself but I don't think many people (under 40) would understand. "Robust" might also work.

I used to work for a man in his mid-seventies who had the vigor of someone in his twenties, (as pertaining to hard work and cheerfulness) we used to refer to him as a "horse", as in: "That guy is no senior-citizen - he's a *horse*." (I guess from "work-horse")

Comment: "hale" and "hearty" and "a horse" are great antonyms for "unhealthy," but "hypochondriacal" is not just about the true state of someone's health.

Comment: I feel ya... But I still think the "horse" thing might fit - Like "Boxer" in "Animal Farm", who simply refused to acknowledge pain or fatigue, so he could continue "doing his part." I think "horse" does imply a state of mind - as well as physicality.

Comment: ..That is true.

Comment: No; this doesn't fit. 'Hyperchondriachal' will if and when it's 'accepted into the lexicon' (whatever _that_ means).

Comment: Except for the problem that when people mispronounce "hypochondriac", they use "hyper" - and mostly get away with it. It's the "chondriac" part that clinches it - the distinction of hypo and hyper isn't enough. Anyway, your etymology is flawed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hyperchondriacal would not make sense. Hypochondriac is not someone who is deficient in chondria... it is derived from the word 'hypochondrium' (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypochondrium).

Comment: @Dave Manger You're assuming that English has to follow some arbitrary set of rules. It's often unruly and quirky. Would you reject 'donkey's years' because of dodgy etymology? Or do you believe that only historical manglings should be acceptable? UrbanDictionary already has: **hyperchondriac**:
someone who has insufficient interest in his health; opposite of hypochondriac. // You're close to the 'etymological fallacy' here. To quote Tim Lymington in another thread, ['The meaning of a word does not depend on its derivation'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy).

Comment: 'My etymology' is _not_ flawed (at least on this occasion); please point out where I specified that it was following the usual pattern of prefix substitution. It's a quirky attempt at neologism based on similarity of form. It may well catch on; English is a living, not fossilised, language. On the other hand, 'hale and hearty' is the opposite of 'sick', not hypochondriacal.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth- Sorry, didn't mean to make it personal - what I meant was close to comment by Dave Magner. Anyway, I can only envision "hyperchondriac" as coming to mean "a really over-the-top hypochondriac".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I certainly agree that the language is alive, I also agree with your assessment that 'hale and hearty' deals with real state of health while hypochondriac deals with perceived state of health. I in fact had come to the comments to suggest hyperchondriac (although kind of as a joke) and just wanted to point out the actual etymology of the word.

Comment: @Dave Manger 'Hyperchondriacal would not make sense' sounds rather pejorative. The derivation is obviously non-standard, but  punning is rarely considered to 'not make sense'. It might be considered _cheesy_. But I have yet to see a book on morphology that actually bans neologisms involving puns. // I don't say that inclusion of _hyperchondriac_ in UD is proof of wordness, but it's the best authority cited here.

Comment: From an internet resume:  Richard Knowles, Professor of English at UW-Madison (Emeritus) and one of the editors of Shakespeare’s plays for the New Variorum Edition (published by the Modern Language Association), discusses characteristics of Shakespeare’s grammar and of Early Modern English in general. Part I of this podcast focuses on Shakespeare’s vocabulary — invented words, borrowed words, derived words, inkhorn words, puns, and malapropisms. // Doubtless, many are acceptable as words today.